# Modifying dictionary inside a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, object, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
def modify_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict = {'b': 2}
    print(my_dict)


def main():
    my_dict = {'a': 1}
    modify_dict(my_dict)
    print(my_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and it's output is:

```
{'b': 2}
{'a': 1}
```

My question is why are the changes done to the dictionary inside the function aren't being reflected in the `main()` function?
Also, how can I update the dictionary inside the function so that the changes are reflected outside of the function?

Comment: You're just re-assigning `my_dict` in `modify_dict`.

Comment: You could return the dictionnary you make inside `modify_dict()` and assign this return to `my_dict()` from your `main()` function.

Comment: Make `modify_dict` returns new value and then `my_dict = modify_dict(my_dict)`

Comment: @IronFist You don't even need to pass `my_dict` to `modify_dict()` in this case.

Comment: @vmonteco .. thought OP wanted to change `my_dict` not to make a new one...since he said *update the dictionary ...so that the changes are...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `my_dict` parameter of `modify_dict` is a local variable to your function. It contains a reference to your dictionary, but it itself is simply a local variable. If you reach in and modify the dictionary it points to, that would work. For example:

```
def modify_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict['b'] = 2
    print(my_dict)
```

Will add to your dictionary. In effect, you are simply assigning a new dictionary to a local variable called my_dict in your function.

As [@vmonteco suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600413/3190891), the best way to achieve this is to simply return the new dictionary from your function and assign the return value.

Comment: I don't want to add `{'b':2}` to it. I just want to assign the function parameter `my_dict` to a new dictionary. I don't want the previous entries to exist.

Comment: I understand, you can't really do that, you would be better returning your new dictionary and saving it that way.

Comment: Also, could you explain why is this happening? This kind of code used to work in C++.

Comment: the my_dict parameter is local to modify_dict.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to 'pass by reference'?

Comment: the dictionary itself is passed by reference - hence the fact you can modify it, but the variable the method uses to point to it (i.e. the parameter) is a local name. The my_dict parameter is just a sort of pointer to borrow from C++. (Though even in C++ I think you would need to pass a pointer to the variable name IIRC?)

Comment: Okay, I think I got it!

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, I will try to give a shot. My major programming language is Java, but I think CPython&JVM are the same in this case.

In program runtime, it got stack and heap, the stack is used on method call context storage and the heap is for global objects storage.

ok, then, use you code as example

step 1.

```
my_dict = {'a': 1}
```

it will create a dict(1) **{'a': 1}** in **heap**, and then my_dict is **reference** to the memory address of the dict(1), it means my_dict now is point to an **memory address**, but not the {'a': 1} itself.

step 2.

```
my_dict = modify_dict()
```

ok, then we call modify_dict function inside main function, the program will put context of main function into a stack(stack1), and the go into function **modify_dict** with **my_dict** as argument, now, the program will create a new stack for function modify_dict, and **make a copy of arguments**, this means my_dict argument now is a **reference copy** (point to the dict(1) in heap, got the same value as my_dict variable in main, **but it's a copy**). (indeed, the question has been answer here)

step 3:

```
my_dict = {'b': 2}
```

**my_dict** (a reference point to **dict(1)** in the heap) now is assign to a new dict(2) in heap, remember **my_dict now is not the same with my_dict in main**, **they are point to two different dict in the heap**.

step 4:

program return back to main function, program will pull things from stack, **my_dict now is point to dict(1)**, and dict(1) is not modify in function modify_dict

Sorry for my poor english ：）

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!

Comment: This is really a good question, i think many programmer(java/python) doesn't know the exactly reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the new dictionnary and assign this return value to the `my_dict` in your `main()` function.

```
def modify_dict():
    my_dict = {'b': 2}
    print(my_dict)    
    return my_dict

def main():
    my_dict = {'a': 1}
    my_dict = modify_dict()
    print(my_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output should be :

```
{'b': 2}
{'b': 2}
```

A simpler way would be to direcly return `{'b' : 2}` without even making a local `my_dict` variable, like this :

```
def modify_dict():
    return {'b' : 2}
```

And this would be basically the same that direcly assign the new value `{'b' : 2}` to your variable (`my_dict = {'b' : 2}`), you don't even need a function for that unless if the new value of your dictionnary depends of its previous value.

## why isn't the `my_dict` variable inside `main()` function modified?

When you pass a variable to a function, the function doesn't use it directly.
It only uses a copy of this variable, a new variable that exists only in the function.

So, in a way you have two `my_dict` variables in your case :
 - The one inside your `modify_dict()` function.
 - And the one inside your `main()` function.

When editing `my_dict` in your `modify_dict()` function, you don't edit the one from the `main()` function, just a copy of it.

Comment: You didn't explain the reason why this is happening.

Comment: I thought the way I'm doing this is analogous to 'passing-by-reference' in C++. But, I guess I was wrong; it's more like passing the pointer to the object using 'pass-by-value'. @srowland explained it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your function to not reassign it (so no = sign on it), but instead modify it. It works because dictionaries are mutables.

In python, you can update a dict with a dict.
So just rewrite your function like this:

```
def modify_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict.update({'b': 2})
    print(my_dict)
```

Just got the same problem by using a dictionary to gather output from threads.